# Type of Sampling

Tags: sampling, terminology

I am conducting a research project, and have recruited participants through the organisation that has come on board with the project. What kind of sampling is this? At first I thought it was convenience sampling because the organisation is participating, but now I am not so sure. Participants will be recruited via email (through the organisation's email base) and invited to participate. If anyone could help me out would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct that it is a convenience sample. There could be frame coverage bias. See [this](http://faculty.nps.edu/rdfricke/docs/5123-Fielding-Ch11.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate you getting back to me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your population of interest.

If your goal is to generalize your results to a population beyond the current organization members, then this is definitely a convenience sample, certainly biased at that.

On the other hand, if your population of interest is restricted only to the members of the organization at this specific point in time, and the recruitment e-mail has been sent to all of them with the aim of getting a response from everyone, then this is a *census*.

If your population of interest was still restricted to the members of the organization, but if the recruitment e-mail had been sent purposefully to some specific members only, then the sampling method for your survey would depend on how they were chosen to participate.

Note that no matter if you're in the case of a census or a survey of organization members, there may be a certain amount of partial and total non-response, which is a problem you should address. Besides people not willing to answer or people overlooking their messages, some potential participants may not have an e-mail address at all or can't be reached that way, like people on maternity leave, people on long sick leave, some people with a blue-collar job who don't have a desk/computer at the office and won't answer the survey outside their working hours, etc. Outdated e-mail addresses may be an issue too, as well as people working for the organization but with their e-mail address absent from the organization database.

Comment: The question is quite old, but this is potentially of interest to other people.